# Math notation for heating object

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, computational-physics, notation, software

An object with mass $m$ and heat capacity $c_{p}$ is exposed to heating $P_{th} $[kW] and thermal losses $\dot q$ [kW/°C]. The energy equation illustrating the process of heating it from $T_{max}$ to $T_{min}$ is, if I'm not mistaken:
$$P_{th} \cdot t = m \cdot c_{p} \cdot (T_{max}-T_{min})+\dot q \cdot \int_{}^{t}  (T(t)-T_{ambient})dt$$

I'm determining the time it takes $(t)$ via the following piece of python code, which I'm trying to explain in the context of a thesis:

```
T = T_min
t = 0
while T <= T_max:
    t += 1
    T += (P_th - q*(T - T_ambient)) / (m*cp)
```

Since $t$ is determined by a finite number of discrete steps, the integral notation above would, in my opinion, not be an accurate depiction of this process. I know that iterative processes such as this, are usually denoted by something like: $T_{max}=f^{t}(T_{min})$. Would this be accurate and if yes - how can it be transformed to $t=...$ ?

Comment: I've though of a way, but I'm not sure this is acceptable for a thesis:


"$t_ {max}$ is considered, which denotes the time, to heat the object to the maximum temperature. It is determined as follows:


The temperature is modeled by the following equation:
$$T(t+1) = T(t)+ \dfrac{P_{th}-\dot q(T(t)-T_{ambient})}{V  \cdot \rho_{w}(T(t)) \cdot c_{p_{w}}(T(t)}$$

It can be trivialized as

$$T(t+1)=f(T(t))$$

Given the condition $T(0)=T_{min}$, $t_{max}$ is the number of iterations $n$ until the following condition is met: $$T_{max}=f^{n}(T_{min})$$ 

Is this sufficient?

Comment: Since you seems to take heating power and thermal loss constant, the problem is easily solved analytically (first order differential equation).
Maybe I don't understand something in your question ?

Comment: While the heating power $P_{th}$ is constant, the thermal loss is dependent on the current temperature and therefore not constant ... I wouldn't know how to solve this analytically.

Comment: OK. But the $\overset{\centerdot }{\mathop{q}}\,$ should be inside the integral ?

Comment: Since $\dot q$ refers to the "specific" thermal loss and is therefore constant, I moved it in front of it. The occuring thermal losses are given by $$Q_{loss}=\dot q \cdot (T(t)-T_{ambient})$$ and are therefore dependent on the current temperature $T(t)$

Comment: I have given an answer for the analytical solution when the specific thermal loss is constant. Sorry for my english !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\overset{\centerdot }{\mathop{q}}\,$ is constant, I just write the analytical solution, which have nothing to do with the Python problem. A little bit too long for a simple comment. Hope it can help !

If all is constant, you have the differential equation $m{{c}_{p}}\frac{dT}{dt}+\overset{\centerdot }{\mathop{q}}\,(T-{{T}_{ext}})={{P}_{th}}$

I pose $\delta T=T-{{T}_{ext}}$, $\tau =m{{c}_{p}}/\overset{\centerdot }{\mathop{q}}\,$ and $\delta {{T}_{f}}={{P}_{th}}/\overset{\centerdot }{\mathop{q}}\,$ so the equation is simply $\tau \frac{d\delta T}{dt}+\delta T=\delta {{T}_{f}}$

The solution is $\delta T=C{{e}^{-t/\tau }}+\delta {{T}_{f}}$

At $t = 0$, we have the initial condition :  $\delta {{T}_{\min }}=C+\delta {{T}_{f}}$ or $C=\delta {{T}_{\min }}-\delta {{T}_{f}}$ so $\delta T=(\delta {{T}_{\min }}-\delta {{T}_{f}}){{e}^{-t/\tau }}+\delta {{T}_{f}}$

and finally  $\delta {{T}_{\max }}=(\delta {{T}_{\min }}-\delta {{T}_{f}}){{e}^{-{{t}_{\max }}/\tau }}+\delta {{T}_{f}}$

Conclusion : ${{t}_{\max }}=\tau \ln \left( \frac{\delta {{T}_{f}}-\delta {{T}_{\min }}}{\delta {{T}_{f}}-\delta {{T}_{\max }}} \right)$

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed response! This is very helpful! :)

Comment: Detected a possible error. since $\delta T=T-T_{ext}$, the equation would be $$\tau \dfrac{dT}{dt}+\delta T = \delta T_{f}$$ Right?

Comment: Just tested it in a simulation and it turns out that your solution is right. Still not sure why though :)